# Uncaught ReferenceError: sqPaymentForm is not defined at submitButtonClick

Tags: javascript

When I try to send my form I have this error. It seems when I click on the button sqPaymentForm is not recognized

error

```
Confirmation:81 Uncaught ReferenceError: sqPaymentForm is not defined
        at submitButtonClick (Confirmation:81)
        at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (Confirmation:356)
```

My button with Onclick

```
$process_button_string = '<div class="text-md-right">' . HTML::button($this->app->getDef('text_square_confirm_order'), null, null, 'primary',  ['type' => 'submit', 'params' => 'onclick="submitButtonClick(event)" data-button="payNow" id="sq-creditcard"']) . '</div>';`
```

My script to check about the problem on the error generation

```
    var cardNonce;
    var paymentForm = new SqPaymentForm({
        applicationId: '{$applicationID}',
        inputClass: 'paymentInput',

        callbacks: {
            cardNonceResponseReceived: function(errors, nonce, cardData) {
              if (errors) {
                var errorDiv = document.getElementById('errors');
                var finalMsg = '<span style="display: block;padding:5px 10px;" class="alert alert warning">';
                errorDiv.innerHTML = '';
                errors.forEach(function(error) {
                  finalMsg +=  error.message + ".<br/>";
                });
                finalMsg += '</span>';
                errorDiv.innerHTML = finalMsg;

                } else {
                // This alert is for debugging purposes only.
                //alert('Nonce received! ' + nonce + ' ' + JSON.stringify(cardData));

                // Assign the value of the nonce to a hidden form element
                var nonceField = document.getElementById('card-nonce');
                nonceField.value = nonce;

                // Submit the form
                document.getElementById('form').submit();
              }
            },
            unsupportedBrowserDetected: function() {
              // Alert the buyer that their browser is not supported
            }
          }
        });

        function submitButtonClick(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          sqPaymentForm.requestCardNonce();
        }
```

Comment: You have a var called `paymentForm`; did you mean to call `paymentForm.requestCardNonce();` instead?

Comment: @ChrisG No idea. Than I can tell you 'var paymentForm = new SqPaymentForm({' is correct and also 'event.preventDefault();
          sqPaymentForm.requestCardNonce('

Comment: Is this your own code? What happens if you replace `sqPaymentForm.requestCardNonce();` with `paymentForm.requestCardNonce();` ?

Comment: This is a Square js payment form, to allow for square credit card processing.  FYI. (I believe)